# How to make auto complete available for directories in cdpath for tcsh?

Tags: linux, path, autocomplete, tcsh, csh

I just learned the trick for setting up `cdpath` in [`tcsh`](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?tcsh%281%29) and it looks pretty useful.

However, it seems that auto-complete of sub-folder names doesn't come with it. Is there any trick available on that? It'd be really cool since I'm entering certain directories a lot.

I am using `tcsh` 6.14.00 (Astron).

Comment: Do you have these in your .cshrc?  "set autolist = ambiguous" and "set complete = enhance" ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just added these two into .cshrc, however seems it's not working.

Comment: Did you relog, source the file or start a new csh? (e.g. `exec csh`)? Which version of csh are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I'm not sure about the csh version, how can I tell?

Comment: Try `csh --version`. It probably yields a line similar to this one: "tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (unknown-unknown-FreeBSD) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec"

Comment: Sorry to get back so late. The output of this cmd is `tcsh 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec`

Comment: If you still do not have an answer in a few days you might consider a bounty or moving (not cross posting) the question to Linux and unix. They have some [similar questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-terminal/31179#31179) which did get an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hennes for the tip. Do you know how exactly do I move a question instead of asking there again?

Comment: You can use the [flag] link to ask moderator assistance. They can (sometimes? always?) migrate the post.  As for the possible delay for an answer: 1) Nobody knows. 2) or it is not possible (likely since it would mean searching for autocompletes in your whole cdpath which is resource intensive)  3) or people are not that interested in the answer (then again, I am curious if it is possible and I doubt that I am the only one).

Comment: I just asked a mod. As long as the question is younger than 60 days they can migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using tcsh 6.18.01-3 under Debian Jessie and file complete is available with the TAB key in the same way that its available under bash.

Can you upgrade to the newer version?

Also: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aids suggests that it should just work with TAB for you. Don't use ESC key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .tcshrc:

```
set autoexpand
```

as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19256/tab-autocompletion-and-history-in-tcsh

or

```
set expand-glob
```

for just files

Another source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh